# How to get information from an object?

Tags: java

I have two classes 
the second one looks like 
this:

```
public class personal_id{
privete int id=0;
private String name;
public personal_id(String name){
name=this.name;
id++;
}
}
```

And the main is

```
public class creator{
public static void main(String[]arg){
personal_id obj1=new personal_id("John");
personal_id obj2=new personal_id("Jane");
personal_id obj3=new personal_id("Jim");
personal_id obj4=new personal_id("Lucas");
}
}
```

I think I have created 4 objects. John with id 0, Jane with id 1, Jim with id 2 and Lucas with id 3. Now I want to know how can I get information from the obj3 or some other object. For example I don't know the name and the id of the object. How can I do that?

Comment: You cannot access the `private` members so easily. Either provide *getters* or change `private` to other access specifier. Are you able to modify the `personal_id` class?

Comment: [Read more about access modifiers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/215497/in-java-difference-between-package-private-public-protected-and-private)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have a couple of options, but the generally best approach here is to create getters:

```
public class PersonalId { // ------------------- renamed: it was "personal_id"
    private int id = 0;   // ------------------- fixed: was "privete" instead of "private"
    private String name;
    public PersonalId(String name) { // ------------------- renamed: it was "personal_id"
        this.name = name; // ----------------- fixed: was "name = this.name"
        id++; // this line makes little sense, it's the same as declaring id = 1;
    }

    public int getId() {      // ------------------- added
        return this.id;       // ------------------- added
    }                         // ------------------- added
    public String getName() { // ------------------- added
        return this.name;     // ------------------- added
    }                         // ------------------- added
}
```

And use it like:

```
public class Creator { //  -------------- renamed: was "creator"
    public static void main(String[] arg) {
        PersonalId john = new PersonalId("John");
        System.out.println("John's id: "+ john.getId());
        System.out.println("John's name: "+ john.getName());
    }
}
```

Output:

```
John's id: 1
John's name: John
```

Generally speaking, you could also change the properties' visibility from `private` to `public` (e.g. `private int id = 0;` to `public int id = 0;`) and use it like `System.out.println("John's id: "+ john.id);`, but that is generally frowned upon -- it is considered a bad practice since it does not foster proper object encapsulation.

## Sidenotes

As you can see from the comments, your code also had some other problems.

Firstly, the name of the classes violate [Java naming conventions and guidelines](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/codeconventions-135099.html), in which the name of classes should be camelCase. In other words, you should have `PersonalId` instead of `personal_id`. Also, you should use `Creator` instead of `creator` (notice the first letter, it should be uppercase).

Also your constructor increments `id` in:

```
id++;
```

But that makes little sense, since `id` is declared with a starting value of `0` (`private int id=0;`), `id`'s value will always be `1` after the construction.